# Google Analytics, get Annotations from API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there any method to get Annotations from Google Analytics via their API. Lots of searching hasn't given be any docs or solid answers on if this is possible or not.

Has anyone done this, or know the filters / dimensions I need to use to get Annotations?

Thanks
Jake

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, to this date there's no way to get annotations from the Google Analytics API.

There's an open issue for it.

http://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=53

Feel free to star the issue to get updates, but please don't reply to it with a "Me too" comment.

The issue was open on Jan 2010 and to this date there is no update or comment from Google.

Google internal policy is to not discuss publicly bugs and new features. We know they are aware of this and other omissions on the API, but they won't provide any deadlines, so you should not wait for it in the short term.

At this point I would guess this will never be implemented. In GA4 annotations have not been implemented yet and it's unclear if it ever will, so the feature might be going away for good.

Answer (score 1):

Update 11/12/2020:

I put in a new request for adding and modifying annotations using the API and Google has confirmed they've put in a Features request to their dev team:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169532195

No ETA of course, but hopefully we'll get the feature soon.

Original Post:

Checking back up on this in 2020 and it still seems like this is the case.

Quoted from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3

- List all the Account, Property and View (Profile) information for a user.
- Manage Properties, Views (Profiles), and Goals.
- Manage user permissions for an account hierarchy.
- Retrieve a View (Profile) ID to use with the Core Reporting API.
- Determine which goals are active and access their configured names.
- Manage Links between Analytics properties and Google Ads accounts.
- Manage Remarketing Audiences.